# GCC Vectorization Pragma

Tags: gcc, vectorization, pragma, icc, auto-vectorization

Using intel compiler, a loop can still be vectorized if users confirm no dependencies using `#pragma ivdep`.

I found one in GCC `#pragma GCC ivdep`, but got an error as below:

`warning: ignoring #pragma GCC ivdep [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma GCC ivdep`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"#pragma ivdep" is fully supported starting from **GCC4.9.**

Which GCC version do you use? #pragma ivdep was not officially supported in GCC at least before 2013.

I'm not sure about official support in other GCC4.x sub-versions between 2013 and 2014, although I've seen there were some partial patches for ivdep support before version 4.9.

**In ICC** (which you also mentioned among question tags) #pragma ivdep is supported long ago ( at least last 5 years).

For other compilers: Microsoft supports "#pragma loop ivdep" starting from MSVS 2013. Cray and some other "old school" compilers may support it starting from 1990s, but I'm not sure.

Finally, if you look for cross-platform and standard-ized solution, take a look at OpenMP4.x #pragma omp simd. While it's different sematic and also only supported by GCC4.9 + ICC/IFORT, it could be more beneficial in future, because (as opposed to ivdep) - **pragma omp simd is true standard**, so all compiler vendors will more or less have to support it in future and will have to support the same syntax for it.

Comment: What about `Clang`? Does it have the same syntax?

Comment: CLang (at least some of its forks) should definitely support #pragma omp simd and most likely Clang doesn't support #pragma ivdep which is proprietary extension.

Comment: All big compilers support `#pragma omp simd`, but there is a difference between it and `#pragma ivdep`. The first pragma forces vectorization, whereas the second pragma tells the compiler there is no vector dependencies, but let the compiler decide whether do vectorize the loop or not, depending on its cost model.

Comment: Gcc requires "#pragma GCC ivdep", whereas Clang accepts "#pragma ivdep".